# How to check if an item is already pushed into a mongoose Schema before adding it (node)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

in the app i'm trying to build every comment can have many likes, i have got a comment Schema:

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    account: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Account',
      required: true,
    },
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    likes:[
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account'
      },
    ]
  },
);
```

im actually trying to build like/dislike opération can somone explain to me how can i check if the account have already liked the comment or not ive wrote this function

```
Account.findById(req.user._id, (err, account) => {
        if (err) { return errorSending(res, err, 'Account not found.'); }
        Comment.findById(req.params.commentId, (err, comment) => {
            if (err) { return errorSending(res, err, 'Comment not cound.'); }
            
                if (comment.likes.indexOf(req.user._id) == -1) {
                console.log('notfound');
                comment.likes.push(account);
                comment.save();
            } else {
                console.log('found');

                comment.likes.pull(account);
                comment.save();
            }
           
        }).populate({
            path: 'likes', populate: {
                path: 'account'
            },
        });
    });
```